# Remove a some words from a string based on text

Tags: c#, string

I want to remove a name from a string. i have read so many article about it. They are suggesting to maintain an array list to maintain all the names as items. Is  there any way to remove the name without maintain an array.
I have a string as

```
string stVal="Naresh Jadapalli\r\nChandra shekhar ponnam\r\nBalu midhun gonu guntla";
```

Now I want to remove the name `\r\nbalu midhun gonu guntla` from the string.
Thank you..

Comment: now you are having trouble in `\r\n`. Please double check if it is `\r\n` or `\n\r`.

Comment: sry.. thats \r\n.. I have edited now.. When I use stVal = stVal.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");.. working well. but 1st and last \r\n are not replacing..

Comment: Ok so try my edited answer. I have mentioned this point earlier in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this pattern:

```
(?i)Balu midhun gonu guntla(\r\n)*|(\r\n)+Balu midhun gonu guntla(\r\n)*$
```

See examples:

```
    string pattern = "(?i)Balu midhun gonu guntla(\r\n)*|(\r\n)+Balu midhun gonu guntla(\r\n)*$";

    string stVal = "Balu midhun gonu guntla\r\n\r\nNaresh Jadapalli\r\nNaresh Jadapalli";
    string res1 = Regex.Replace(stVal, pattern, "");

    stVal = "Naresh Jadapalli\r\n\r\nBalu midhun gonu guntla\r\n\r\nChandra shekhar ponnam\r\n\r\nBalu midhun gonu guntla\r\n\r\n";
    string res2 = Regex.Replace(stVal, pattern, "");

    stVal = "Naresh Jadapalli\r\n\r\nChandra shekhar ponnam\r\nChandra shekhar ponnam\r\n\r\nBalu midhun gonu guntla\r\n\r\n";
    string res3 = Regex.Replace(stVal, pattern, "");
```

Comment: as per   stVal = stVal.Replace("\r\nBalu midhun gonu guntla", ""); 1st name will not have \r\n. soo it will not replace the 1st name

Comment: your second regex working to remove 1st \r\n.. not working to remove last \r\n

Comment: can you please provide a sample ?

Comment: ex:the actual string is naresh jadapalli\r\nbalu midhun. If I remove 2nd name the output will be.. balu midhun\r\n

Answer (score 4):

Assuming, that `"balu midhun gonu guntla"` is a typo, and it should be:

```
var strToRemove = "Balu midhun gonu guntla";
```

then the code looks like this:

```
stVal.Remove(stVal.IndexOf(strToRemove), strToRemove.Length);
```

If it isn't a typo, then just use another `IndexOf` overload:

```
stVal.Remove(stVal.IndexOf(strToRemove, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase), strToRemove.Length);
```

Comment: How about `stVal = stVal.Replace("\n\rBalu midhun gonu guntla", "")`?

Comment: @unlimit: Indifferently. Just another way to solve the same task, which is unclear. I mean, does OP want to remove single occurrence or all of the occurrences?

Comment: This solution will crash if the input string does not have the search string. :) So don;t forget to check for existence of the search string.

Comment: @NeverHopeless: did SO ever been a place to get production code, hmmm?

Comment: Agreed, but if it is mentioned, the OP will take care of it, if missing.

Comment: @NareshJadapalli: what king of problem?

Comment: I hava to remove name and \r\n too. for that I am using stVal = stVal.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");.. but it will not work for 1st \r\n and last \r\n.. ex:the actual string is naresh jadapalli\r\nbalu midhun.  If I remove 1st name the output will be.. \r\nbalu midhun

Answer (score 1):

To do this properly you must account for the delimiters.

If you do not then you will have a bug if the name that you are replacing occurs as a substring of another name in the list.

For example, imagine if you were replacing "Matthew" inside this string:

```
"Matthew Smith\r\nMatthew\r\nMatthew Watson"
```

Presumably you would only want to replace the "\r\nMatthew\r\n" in the middle to give:

```
"Matthew Smith\r\nMatthew Watson"
```

But if you ignore the delimiters you would get this:

```
" Smith\r\nMatthew\r\nMatthew Watson"
```

The following method will remove the *first* match, accounting for the delimiters properly. Note that it also has to handle the special cases at the beginning and end of the string, because there is no delimiter at the start or end.

```
/// <summary>This removes the first occurrence  of the specified target string in the given text.</summary>
/// <param name="text">The text from which to remove the target string.</param>
/// <param name="target">The target string to remove.</param>
/// <param name="delimiter">The delimiter string used between potential target strings.</param>
/// <returns>The text with first occurrence  (if any) of the target string removed.</returns>

public static string RemoveFirstMatch(string text, string target, string delimiter)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

    if (target == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

    if (text.StartsWith(target + delimiter))
        return text.Substring(target.Length + delimiter.Length);

    if (text.EndsWith(delimiter + target))
        return text.Substring(0, text.Length - target.Length - delimiter.Length);

    return text.Replace(delimiter + target + delimiter, delimiter);
}
```

Sample test code:

```
string stVal="aaaa\r\naaab\r\naaab\r\naaac";
string delimiter = "\r\n";

Console.WriteLine(RemoveFirstMatch(stVal, "aaaa", delimiter) + "\n-------------");
Console.WriteLine(RemoveFirstMatch(stVal, "aaab", delimiter) + "\n-------------");
Console.WriteLine(RemoveFirstMatch(stVal, "aaac", delimiter) + "\n-------------");
```

Comment: thank you verry much for stVal = stVal.Replace("\n\r\n\r", "\n\r");

Comment: @NareshJadapalli Yes, there are definitely some problems with the naive approach. I'll update my post in a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution for this to use regex find the requried occurances and replace them with required words

you can find  good sample at [C# RegEx Match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)